# Customize discussion board xslt

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, discussion-board, item-styles

I wanted to modify the xslt file that displays discussion board threads. I tried to find the xslt in "Style Library" -> "XSL Style Sheets" but could not find the stylesheet there. Where can I find the stylesheet and attach it to my discussion board for customized view of replies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change XSLT for Discussion Board, deploy via VS2010](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19634/change-xslt-for-discussion-board-deploy-via-vs2010)

Answer (score 1):

Somebody already had the same question, check the following URL: [Change XSLT for Discussion Board, deploy via VS2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19634/change-xslt-for-discussion-board-deploy-via-vs2010)

Regards, Estruyf